# Good book on English grammar from the very beginning

Tags: grammar, books

My wife is fairly new in US and her native language is Ukrainian. Though she is not afraid of speaking english, she does it with lots of grammar mistakes, starting from wrong sequence of words in a sentence to wrong times used to wrong sequence in a question. I was trying to find a thorough book on beginner grammar, but found that most books lack consistency, jump form subject to subject, don't go into deep details explaining rules and don't really start from the very basics.

She will need to take ACCUPLACER exam for nursing program and I'm afraid she doesn't have necessary knowledge to pass the english grammar part of it.

Any recommendations on a good grammar book for a ESL person in need of building a decent grammar base?

P.S. English is not my first language either, so don't pick on my grammar here :)

Comment: Hello Andrey. Sorry but your question is off topic for this site, as per the [FAQ] (the point "How to improve my English"); therefore I'm voting to close. But please, keep contributing to the site! :)

Comment: There is an interesting & short & well organized grammar book called `<Grammar for English Language Teachers>`, it's very good & easy to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many, and it's probably best to get recommendations from an ESL teacher who has had a chance to assess her level of English and her requirements. However, two good reference works for foreign learners are '[An A-Z of English Grammar and Usage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582405742)' and the '[Cambridge Grammar of English](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521674395)'. There is also a series of grammar books, with exercises, at different levels entitled '[English Grammar in Use](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675804)'.

There are a couple of books for native speakers by the British linguist David Crystal which may also be of interest: '[Discover Grammar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582294355)' and '[Rediscover Grammar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582848628)'.

EDIT: On re-reading your post, I think the titles I have suggested may be too advanced. My advice to consult a well qualified teacher remains.

Comment: for a non-native speaker if you were to choose one book between *'An A-Z of English Grammar and Usage* and *Cambridge Grammar of English*, which one would you suggest and why?

Comment: The first is more user-friendly.

Comment: In terms of completeness and correctness you still prefer the first one?

Comment: I haven't compared them side by side, but since I bought the second, my view of it has been coloured by Rodney Huddleston's review of it reported here: http://english-jack.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/more-muddled-grammar.html